# Authentication is required to start 'asterisk.service'

Tags: command-line, server, sudo, aws, asterisk

On `aws` I cannot seem to start `asterisk`:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-14-19:~$ 
ubuntu@ip-172-31-14-19:~$ systemctl status asterisk.service
● asterisk.service - Asterisk PBX
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/asterisk.service; enabled; vendor preset: enab
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2017-11-14 08:45:1
     Docs: man:asterisk(8)
  Process: 24907 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/asterisk -g -f -U asterisk (code=exited, status=
 Main PID: 24907 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 14 08:45:14 ip-172-31-14-19 systemd[1]: asterisk.service: Main process exited, co
Nov 14 08:45:14 ip-172-31-14-19 systemd[1]: asterisk.service: Unit entered failed sta
Nov 14 08:45:14 ip-172-31-14-19 systemd[1]: asterisk.service: Failed with result 'exi
lines 1-10/10 (END)
ubuntu@ip-172-31-14-19:~$
```

To start the [service](https://voxilla.com/2009/02/13/asterisk-amazon-ec2/), create a sudo user first?

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-14-19:~$ 
ubuntu@ip-172-31-14-19:~$ uptime
 22:05:27 up 0 min,  1 user,  load average: 2.44, 0.65, 0.22
ubuntu@ip-172-31-14-19:~$ 
ubuntu@ip-172-31-14-19:~$ asterisk -rvvvv
Unable to connect to remote asterisk (does /var/run/asterisk/asterisk.ctl exist?)
ubuntu@ip-172-31-14-19:~$ 
ubuntu@ip-172-31-14-19:~$ sudo asterisk -rvvvv
Unable to connect to remote asterisk (does /var/run/asterisk/asterisk.ctl exist?)
ubuntu@ip-172-31-14-19:~$ 
ubuntu@ip-172-31-14-19:~$ sudo asterisk -cvvvvvvvvvv
Asterisk already running on /var/run/asterisk/asterisk.ctl.  Use 'asterisk -r' to connect.
ubuntu@ip-172-31-14-19:~$ 
ubuntu@ip-172-31-14-19:~$ asterisk -r
Unable to connect to remote asterisk (does /var/run/asterisk/asterisk.ctl exist?)
ubuntu@ip-172-31-14-19:~$ 
ubuntu@ip-172-31-14-19:~$ asterisk -rvv
Unable to connect to remote asterisk (does /var/run/asterisk/asterisk.ctl exist?)
ubuntu@ip-172-31-14-19:~$ 
ubuntu@ip-172-31-14-19:~$ /etc/init.d/asterisk start
[....] Starting asterisk (via systemctl): asterisk.service==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to start 'asterisk.service'.
Authenticating as: Ubuntu (ubuntu)
Password: 
polkit-agent-helper-1: pam_authenticate failed: Authentication failure
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ===
Failed to start asterisk.service: Access denied
See system logs and 'systemctl status asterisk.service' for details.
 failed!
ubuntu@ip-172-31-14-19:~$
```

specific directions:

> Step 10. Starting Asterisk
>
> Now we can start Asterisk, run the following command to start the
>   asterisk on the command line:
>
> asterisk -cvvvvvvvvvv
>
> If Asterisk starts ok, type:
>
> core stop now
>
> to shutdown Asterisk and exit the Asterisk console.
>
> Then start asterisk as a daemon:
>
> /etc/init.d/asterisk start
>
> Then you can connect to the Asterisk console with the following
>   command:
>
> asterisk -rvvvvvvvvvv

unlike the [local](https://askubuntu.com/q/976112/45156) system, there's no known password for the default user on `aws`.

Comment: Can you please post the output of `systemctl status asterisk.service`.

Comment: @NerdOfCode added the output; hit `ctrl-c` to exit from that.